# titleformat horizontal spacing between title and body paragraph

Tags: titlesec

My question is similar to https://superuser.com/questions/12583/text-to-the-right-of-a-sectiontitle-in-latex-the-normal-case-is-text-comes

I tried using an exmaple from the "The titlesec, titleps and titletoc Packages"

the code is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[top=1truein,bottom=1truein,left=1truein,right=1truein]{geometry}

% define section
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont\vspace{12pt}
    \vspace{6pt}%
    \sffamily\bfseries\filleft }
{\thesection\\}{.5em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{1pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}

\begin{document}


\section*{\large OK} 
this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section*{\large Averylongtitle} 
this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example 
\end{document}
```

And here is the result.
[image]

As you can see the title is overlapping with the body text.
I tried changing `\titlespacing`  but it does not work.

**Note**: I prefer the body text to start right after the title at the same horizontal line, just like the first example. However, when the section title name is too long, the name and text overlap.

Comment: Could you please provide whole code you tried.

Comment: @mmr Thanks for the reply. I have provided the whole code example

Answer (score 0):

You can use even less code for spacing. Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% define section


\begin{document}

    \section{\large Averylongtitle} 
    this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example 

    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\hspace{-5em}\thesection}{1em}{}

    \section{\large Averylongtitle} 
    this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example 
    
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Approach 2:** You can try another approach.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{0pt}
    \section*{\large Averylongtitle}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example this is an example 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I did not explain clearly, but I want the body text to locate right after the section title, as shown in my new picture.

Comment: @jchan192 A very long title will start from left margin, right? I think this time your need is served. Answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update . and Yes start from left margin but I will want the body text will start at the same line as the title.

Comment: @jchan192 Then apply **approach 2** and move `\end{adjustwidth}` at the end of all section text.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. 
Sorry, I didn't mean same vertical line, but the same horizontal line

Comment: @jchan192 Then how can you accomodate a long title in small space?

Comment: See: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters#Customize_chapters_and_sections

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want unnumbered sections.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1truein,bottom=1truein,left=1truein,right=1truein]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% define section
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\hspace*{-40pt}\makesectiontitle}
\newcommand{\makesectiontitle}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\dimen0<34pt \makebox[34pt][l]{#1}\else #1\fi
}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{6pt}

\begin{document}


\section{I}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{II}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{III}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{IIII}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{IIIII}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{IIIIII}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{IIIIIII}
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\section{A very long title} 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 
this is an example this is an example this is an example 

\end{document}
```

If the title is “short”, that is, a minimum space of 6pt is ensured, then a box of the appropriate size is used. Otherwise the title is run in.

[image]